# Unable to connect via Java to a DSE graph

Tags: gremlin, datastax-enterprise-graph

Am a newbie. Installed and ran DSE graph.

Versions used
DSE - 5.1.3
TinkerPop Java Driver - 3.3.0

Now I am trying to remote connect from my java program. My graph name is `mygraph and my client program is something like

```
Cluster cluster = Cluster.build().port(8182).create();
Client client = cluster.connect().alias("mygraph");
ResultSet resultSet = client.submit("g.V()");
resultSet.stream().forEach(System.out::println);
```

However it results in below exception. Am guessing its mostly

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: io.netty.handler.codec.DecoderException: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.SerializationException: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 121, Size: 0
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.reportJoin(CompletableFuture.java:375)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.join(CompletableFuture.java:1934)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ResultSet.one(ResultSet.java:107)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ResultSet$1.hasNext(ResultSet.java:159)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using the DataStax provided Java Driver?

Manual - http://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver-dse/1.4/manual/graph/
Please note we are updating our docs to reflect the DataStax Java Driver Fluent API mechanism for executing Gremlin - https://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/datastax-drivers-fluent-apis-for-dse-graph-are-out

We recommend using the Fluent API method of executing Gremlin.

Comment: I would like to stick to Tinkerpop so it provides me a flexibility. Am sure the datastax driver will work fine

Comment: Am going to mark this as the right answer, Since the approach I am going to take is to use use DSE java driver to get to a DseSession and then use DSEGraph to convert it to a GraphTraversalSource